# How to sum amount based on the occurrences of repeated dates in an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this array

```
const data =[
             {total: 90, date:"2021-11-16T07:20:23.000Z"},
             {total: 10, date:"2021-11-16T07:20:23.000Z"},
             {total: 50, date:"2021-11-17T07:20:23.000Z"}
            ];
```

i want to sort this array so the objects that have same date i want to sum the values of the total and the number of these objects with same date with new property called count.
result should looks like

```
const newData =[
                { total: 100, date:"2021-11-16T07:20:23.000Z", count:2},
                { total: 50, date:"2021-11-17T07:20:23.000Z", count:1}
              ];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a free coding service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: perhaps something for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with getting an array of unique date occurence with the help of `...new Set()`, then loop through those and when looping filter the original array and map the values.

As others have suggested, nobody here will provide you with the complete code, but at least now you have an idea of how to start.